# PHP check_login to divide my admin panel up

Tags: php, security

I have an admin area for my site built with PHP and I have a function `check_login();`
to determine what a user can see based on user level.
What would be the proper way to write an if statement so when a user logs in it takes them to the appropriate place?

```
check_login('1'); --> 1st highest area
```

if

```
check_login('2'); --> 2nd highest area
```

else_if

```
check_login('3'); --> 3rd highest area
```

Answer (score 1):

I've become fond of `switch`:

*Note: This operates under the presumption that `check_login()` returns a `boolean` value.*

```
define('ADMIN', 1); // etc
switch(true){
    case(check_login(ADMIN)):
        // do admin stuff
        break;
    case(check_login(REGISTERED)):
        // do registered stuff
        break;
    case(check_login(UNREGISTERED)):
        // do unregistered stuff
        break;
    default:
        // fails all conditions
        exit('get outta here');
        break;
}
```

I find it easier to read in some circumstances, such as this. Furthermore, given you're setting properties for the session or whatever, you can omit the `break` statements, and let the cases fall through, so that *administrative* users also aggregate the properties of the lesser account types.

Answer (score 0):

If your check_login function return primary datatypes like '1' and '2' then I would think that a switch would be the best.

[w3schools - switch](http://w3schools.com/PHP/php_switch.asp)